# Sql server agent where to find

Tags: sql-server

In my object explorer I can't find the sql server agent. How can I activate this in SQL Express server? I want to activate this to make it possible to configure , based on time to refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Agent is not included in SQL Server Express edition

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/890726/sql-server-agent-not-appearing-in-management-studi

Comment: Thank you for the answer, couldn't found this anywhere that clear.